# Anthill remoting API ClassDefNotFound error

Tags: java, anthill

I am trying to automate BUILDS with anthill3 using remoting API but am getting an error when i try to get the Workflows from a project.

It seems the jar commons-graph.jar which is required to run this is not provided in anthill3-devkit.

As per the below link it says to download the JAr from anthill 5 , but i get an error when i try to download any fixes or release of anthill5 .
So if anybody has a resolution or the required JAR it will be very helpfull.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI43350

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     Lcom/urbancode  /commons/graph/TableDisplayableGraph;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question its hard to understand why you are getting the error and why you might need JAR from a newer version of Anthill. From what I know, even sending you the JAR won't do the job because of the different versions. Please try to explain what is exactly you try and maybe we can find another way of doing it without using upper version

Anyway how can I send it to you ? E-mail ?

Thanks,
Elyahu

Comment: Thanks Elyahu , the issue was resolved after i took the updated JAR from my BUILD management team. Of course i had to take the JAR from a latest anthill version as prescribed in the below link. [IBM link ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI43350)

Comment: could you please have a quick look on this issue if don't mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677098/how-to-find-the-latest-dependency-easily-in-anthillpro3-remoting-script