# How to find the latest Dependency easily in Anthillpro3 Remoting script

Tags: java, anthill

I want to Automate the process of Branch creation in our project.Below are the steps which are being done manually using the Anthill Web UI.
In our Anthill we have around 250 Java projects whose workflows are named after their release names like RB-16.4.5.

**Step 1:** Copy the workflow of each project with current branch like **RB-16.4.5**.

**Step 2:** Edit the Workflow name to new Branch name like RB-16.4.6 and change the source URL to latest branch name like **somelocation/branches/16.4.6/projects/ProjectA**

**Step 3:** For many of the project we have added Dependents in Anthill.So we would want to update them with latest Branch projects.So what we do is that we delete the old dependencies with old Branch names like  **ProjectA RB-16.4.5** and add new dependencies by going to Administration TAB of the new Workflow created and Search for the new project with **Folder name ProjectA RB-16.4.6**

Now the code which i have written is working fine for the first two steps But am unable to find how i could write code for Step 3.Since am unable to figure out how to get the latest Dependency Project of the new workflow we created above. from Anthill documentation.We cannot set or change the name of Dependency to new one.

I have gone through the official Java Remoting API available at http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/documentation/product_doc/UrbanCode/AnthillPro/remoting/api/index.html

```
AnthillClient client;
String currentBranch="RB-16.4.5";
String newBranch="RB-16.4.6";

UnitofWork uow=client.createUnitOfWork();

Folder[] allFolders=FolderFactory.getInstance().restoreAll();
Project[] myProjects={};

for(int i=0;i<allFolders.length;i++){
if(allFolders[i].getName().equals("MyPrjFolder")){
myProjects=allFolders[i].getProjects();
break;
}
//For each project copy the workflow and set New branch name & Source URL
for(int j=0;j<myProjects.length;j++){
 Workflow flow=WorkflowLookup.getForProjectAndName(myProjects[j],newBranch);

 Workflow newworkFlow=flow.duplicateForCopy(myProjects[j]);
 newworkFlow.setUnitOfWork(uow);
 newworkFlow.setName(newBranch);
 newworkFlow.setNew(true);
 newworkFlow.setActive(true);

 SvnSourceConfig svnConfig=
 (SvnSourceConfig)         newWorkFlow.getBuildProfile().getSourceConfig();
 SvnModule[] svnModule=svnConfig.getModuleArray();
 String sourceURL=svnModule[0].getUrl();
 svnModule[0].setUrl(sourceURL.replace(currentBranch,newBranch));

// Store the dependencies of old project branch  in a list
 Dependency   
 existingDependencies=flow.getBuildProfile().getAnthillDependencyArray();
 someList.add(existingDependencies);
 }


 /*Now how do i set the Dependencies for each Project with new Project of
  the new Branch if i have already stored the old dependecies of projects*/
// Code to create and add dependency should be something like 
// How do i get the newDependency value which refers to the Project under   new workflow created
 Dependency newDependency=null;
 newDependency=    Dependency.createDependency(existingDependencies[i].getDependent),newDependency.getDependency());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about a different approach ? Get the branch name as input from the end user ?

Comment: Elyahu could you please clarify...Currently the user has to provide the current branch & new branch to be created as variables in the above program code and then run it to create a new Branch .But am unable to figure out how to get the dependencies updated to the latest versions after copying the workflows.

Comment: You can use AnthillPro Properties for workflow.
Administration -> Project -> Worflow -> Properties TAB
See if it suites you

Comment: @SumatejaKonge please try to reply on your question so others can understand if this information is helpful. Thanks

Comment: Oops sorry Elyahu...Actually i tried to use the Properties but i could not figure how the names of the project dependencies could be changed to point to the latest branch name when i use properties.I added a new properties which can be used to specify the latest branch name but when i copy the existing workflow i want the dependencies to be updated to latest branch project , what would be the trigger to this.?

Comment: First, try this site
http://epicforce.net/build-and-release/category/anthill-pro
Second, Ill try to answer more thorouly later. Ill update my answer then